# Logstash flush pipeline before shutdown

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash 5.4.2 Persistence Queue. Where I have config file to get input throw JDBC and do some transformations and storing output to mongo db. But when I run this in logstash it inserts only few records let us say 6000 where as the actual output should be 300000 records. And main pipeline gets shutdown. When I see the page file in data folder has more number of records. How to flush the data into output without pipeline before or after shutdown. My logstash persistence queue setting as follows.

```
pipeline.workers: 2
pipeline.output.workers: 1
pipeline.batch.size: 50
pipeline.batch.delay: 5
pipeline.unsafe_shutdown: false
config.test_and_exit: false
config.reload.automatic: false
queue.type: persisted
queue.page_capacity: 1gb
queue.max_events: 0
queue.max_bytes: 4gb
queue.checkpoint.acks: 1024
queue.checkpoint.writes: 1024
queue.checkpoint.interval: 1000
```

Is there any way to flush all data from persistence queue to output during main pipeline shutdown or anyway of workaround to handle this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `queue.checkpoint.writes` is set to `1024`, which is a default. You need to set it to `1`, to [guarantee maximum durability](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html#durability-persistent-queues) for input events, i.e.

```
queue.checkpoint.writes: 1
```

Please remember that this involves heavy disk writing which will impact performance severely.